# Django Spanning multi-valued relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Sked(models.Model):
    pass

class Class(models.Model):
    class_key = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Sked_class(models.Model):
    class_room = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    sked = models.ForeignKey(Sked)
    class_took = models.ForeignKey(Class)

class User(djmodels.User):
    sked = models.ForeignKey(Sked, null=True)
```

I want to make a query that selects all the classes that a specific user is taking, but i still can't get the idea of how to do it without using SQL, I already read this document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/ , but I still don't get it, How can I span multi-valued relationships through this models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for two things - how to span foreign keys, and how to only return a unique set of classes that doesn't include duplicates.

You span foreign keys using `__` to separate the relationships, and use `distinct()` on the query set to filter out duplicates.  Remember that foreign key relationships work both ways with Django syntax, as the ORM will recognize reverse relationships.  This should work:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
Class.objects.filter(sked_class__user=user).distinct()
```

It's unclear to me if you data model makes sense, however.  I think this makes more sense:

```
class Class(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Schedule(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User)
    classes = models.ManyToManyField(Class)
```

Then you'd say:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
Class.objects.filter(schedule__student=user)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!, now I understand it. And about your suggestion for the data model I think that your suggestion would work better If i make some little changes to my whole data model, but the thing is I did not share all the structure of the data models and the logic for the app behind it. But I will consider it.!!